# How to pass one of that parameters as argument to this shell script

Tags: shell

I have a function which is taking 2 parameters,i am trying to invoke a shell script and I need to pass one of that parameters as argument to this shell script how can i do that

Comment: How are you calling your function? What does your function look like? Have you tried passing the argument to your script at all?

Answer (score 0):

You just include them after the calling of the script:

```
sh shellscript.sh arg1 arg2
```

Then you would reference them in your shell script as $1 and $2.